# Find out the extension part of URL saved in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How to find out and save the extension of fields that i am going to save in photo album. i want know it which format.
example:

http://www.example.com/myvideo.mp4,
http://www.example.com/mypicture.png

I need is like  .mp4 and .png.If possible give me example code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation for `NSString`? You just need to send `-pathExtension` to your string.

If you're dealing with a string containing a URL, you should first convert it to an `NSURL`, then extract the path:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://...";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSString *path = [url path];
NSString *extension = [path pathExtension];
```

Comment: Isn't pathExtension a method of NSURL directly?

Answer (score 9):

NSURL also have pathExtension (Available in iOS 4.0 and later.)

```
NSString *extension = [[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://sample.example.com/path/hellowwrod.ext"] pathExtension];
```

Answer (score 6):

refer a following code.

```
NSString *path = @"http://www.mysite.com/myvideo.mp4";
NSString *lastPath = [path lastPathComponent];
NSString *fileExtension = [lastPath pathExtension]; // [path pathExtension];
NSLog(@"%@", lastPath); //myvideo.mp4
NSLog(@"%@", fileExtension); // mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift:

```
let stringUrl = " http://www.example.com/mypicture.png"
let url = URL(string: stringUrl)
let path = url?.path
let fileExtension = url?.pathExtension
```